# Access data from a Lazy Sequence

Tags: clojure

I am trying to retrieve data from a DB. The data is coming back in a lazy sequence. I can peek at the data in repl and it looks like this:

```
({:foo value1, :bar value2})
```

How can I get at this data? preferably, how can I turn it into a map? I've tried:

(doall sequence (get sequence :foo))
Which just returns nil. And

```
(apply hash-map user-settings)
```

which returns

```
llegalArgumentException No value supplied for key: {:foo value1, :bar value2} clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap.create (PersistentHashMap.java:77)
```

I am very new to clojure and have been stuck on this for way too long. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *The data is coming back in a lazy sequence*  - A  lazy sequence of what? You have a sequence of one record represented by map `{:foo value1, :bar value2}`. Can you have several such records? How do you want to combine them into a map/table? Is there a key within the record you want to index them by?

Answer (score 3):

You already have a map, it just happens to be the only item in your list.

```
(def data (first '({:foo 123 :bar 456})))

(:foo data)  ; => 123
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when you want to print lazy seq to see your data use `into`. For example if you want to see contents of a lazy vector use `(into [] your-lazy-vector)` or `(into {} your-lazy-map)`.

You can do this uncool conversion within a println function or in a let. However, I recommend removing this kind of debugging aid before release or pull-request.

Lazy sequences are great, most of the time.